# Boost regular expression syntax validation

Tags: c++, regex, boost

A simple description of the problem is that I need to receive a regular expression as input and check if any given string matches it.

My question: Is there a way to verify that the given regex input has valid syntax? I am using boost and POSIX regular expressions (not sure if it is important whether basic or extended regular expressions are used, the problem remains the same.) Is there even a "wrong" syntax for regular expressions?

Answer (score 2):

http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/libs/regex/doc/html/boost_regex/ref/basic_regex.html#boost_regex.basic_regex.construct3

> **Throws:** `bad_expression` if [p1,p2) is not a valid regular expression, unless the flag `no_except` is set in f.